# Using tasks getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, task, nullreferenceexception

first of all, I already searched through SO in many NullReferenceException questions. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985545/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198403/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object)

I am getting an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when I try to call `Task.WaitAll(tasks);`

I am sure that I am initializing the all the objects before trying to call methods. Below is the code snipet:

```
public IList<ResourceFreeBusyDto> GetResourceFreeBusy(int requesterId, int[] resourceIds, DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        IList<ResourceFreeBusyDto> result = new List<ResourceFreeBusyDto>();

        ValidateFreeBusyInputs(resourceIds, start, end);

        List<Task<IList<ResourceFreeBusyDto>>> tasks = new List<Task<IList<ResourceFreeBusyDto>>>();
        TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0,0,30); // 30 seconds          

        // Split resources to persons and meetingRooms
        List<int> personIds;
        List<int> meetingRoomIds;

        SplitResourceIds(resourceIds, out personIds, out meetingRoomIds);

        // Go online for persons
        if (personIds.Count > 0)
        {
            //result.AddRange(GetResourceFreeBusyOnline(requesterId, personIds.ToArray(), start, end)); // paralelizovat
            Task<IList<ResourceFreeBusyDto>> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetResourceFreeBusyOnline(requesterId, personIds.ToArray(), start, end));
            tasks.Add(task);
        }

        // Go online for meetingrooms if they are not cached in DB
        if (meetingRoomIds.Count > 0)
        {
            DateTime? lastModifiedMeetingRoomFreeBusy = new DateTime();

            lastModifiedMeetingRoomFreeBusy = freeBusyRepository.GetMinTimeStamp();

            if (lastModifiedMeetingRoomFreeBusy.Value.AddMinutes(1) < DateTime.UtcNow || lastModifiedMeetingRoomFreeBusy == null)
            {
                //result.AddRange(GetResourceFreeBusyOnline(requesterId, meetingRoomIds.ToArray(), start, end)); // mrIDs
                Task<IList<ResourceFreeBusyDto>> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetResourceFreeBusyOnline(requesterId, resourceIds, start, end));
                tasks.Add(task);
            }
            else
            {
                //result.AddRange(GetMeetingRoomsFreeBusyCached(requesterId, meetingRoomIds.ToArray(), start, end)); // mrIDs
                Task<IList<ResourceFreeBusyDto>> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetMeetingRoomsFreeBusyCached(requesterId, resourceIds, start, end));
                tasks.Add(task);
            }
        }

        bool status = false;

        try
        {
            var a = tasks.ToArray();
            Task.WaitAll(a);
            status = Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray(), timeout);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Log.Fatal(ex);
        }


        if (status == false)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(
            string.Format("Timeout expired." +
            " The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the asynchronous importing task executing" +
            " or the server is not responding. Try it later!"));
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Task<IList<ResourceFreeBusyDto>> task in tasks)
            {
                result.AddRange(task.Result);
            }
        }

        return result;

    }
```

**NOTE**

```
var a = tasks.ToArray();
Task.WaitAll(a);
```

is the test where an exception is thrown. `var a = tasks.ToArray();` is passing without an error.

Exception is thrown here:

```
Task.WaitAll(a);
```

and here

```
status = Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray(), timeout);
```

Can you please explain me what is happening? I can see during the debugging that `tasks` is initialized.

P.S. the commented lines for example: `result.AddRange(GetResourceFreeBusyOnline(requesterId, meetingRoomIds.ToArray(), start, end));` are the lines calling the methods in single thread which is passing without an error and returning the expected result.

**Stack**

```
2016-12-22 13:24:18,844 [9] FATAL Tieto.MyMeetings.Tasks.FreeBusy.FreeBusyTasks - System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at SharpArch.NHibernate.Web.Mvc.WebSessionStorage.GetSimpleSessionStorage()
   at SharpArch.NHibernate.Web.Mvc.WebSessionStorage.GetSessionForKey(String factoryKey)
   at SharpArch.NHibernate.NHibernateSession.CurrentFor(String factoryKey)
   at SharpArch.NHibernate.NHibernateRepositoryWithTypedId`2.get_Session()
   at SharpArch.NHibernate.LinqRepositoryWithTypedId`2.FindAll()
   at Tieto.MyMeetings.Tasks.FreeBusy.FreeBusyTasks.GetResourceFreeBusyOnline(Int32 requesterId, Int32[] resourceIds, DateTime start, DateTime end) in C:\_Hg\Tieto.MyMeetings\source\server\Tieto.MyMeetings.Tasks\FreeBusy\FreeBusyTasks.cs:line 238
   at Tieto.MyMeetings.Tasks.FreeBusy.FreeBusyTasks.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<GetResourceFreeBusy>b__0() in C:\_Hg\Tieto.MyMeetings\source\server\Tieto.MyMeetings.Tasks\FreeBusy\FreeBusyTasks.cs:line 83
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(Task[] tasks, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(Task[] tasks, Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(Task[] tasks)
   at Tieto.MyMeetings.Tasks.FreeBusy.FreeBusyTasks.GetResourceFreeBusy(Int32 requesterId, Int32[] resourceIds, DateTime start, DateTime end) in C:\_Hg\Tieto.MyMeetings\source\server\Tieto.MyMeetings.Tasks\FreeBusy\FreeBusyTasks.cs:line 113
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at SharpArch.NHibernate.Web.Mvc.WebSessionStorage.GetSimpleSessionStorage()
   at SharpArch.NHibernate.Web.Mvc.WebSessionStorage.GetSessionForKey(String factoryKey)
   at SharpArch.NHibernate.NHibernateSession.CurrentFor(String factoryKey)
   at SharpArch.NHibernate.NHibernateRepositoryWithTypedId`2.get_Session()
   at SharpArch.NHibernate.LinqRepositoryWithTypedId`2.FindAll()
   at Tieto.MyMeetings.Tasks.FreeBusy.FreeBusyTasks.GetResourceFreeBusyOnline(Int32 requesterId, Int32[] resourceIds, DateTime start, DateTime end) in C:\_Hg\Tieto.MyMeetings\source\server\Tieto.MyMeetings.Tasks\FreeBusy\FreeBusyTasks.cs:line 238
   at Tieto.MyMeetings.Tasks.FreeBusy.FreeBusyTasks.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<GetResourceFreeBusy>b__0() in C:\_Hg\Tieto.MyMeetings\source\server\Tieto.MyMeetings.Tasks\FreeBusy\FreeBusyTasks.cs:line 83
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<---

---> (Inner Exception #1) System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at SharpArch.NHibernate.Web.Mvc.WebSessionStorage.GetSimpleSessionStorage()
   at SharpArch.NHibernate.Web.Mvc.WebSessionStorage.GetSessionForKey(String factoryKey)
   at SharpArch.NHibernate.NHibernateSession.CurrentFor(String factoryKey)
   at SharpArch.NHibernate.NHibernateRepositoryWithTypedId`2.get_Session()
   at SharpArch.NHibernate.LinqRepositoryWithTypedId`2.FindAll(ILinqSpecification`1 specification)
   at Tieto.MyMeetings.Tasks.FreeBusy.FreeBusyTasks.GetMeetingRoomsFreeBusyCached(Int32 requesterId, Int32[] meetingRoomIds, DateTime start, DateTime end) in C:\_Hg\Tieto.MyMeetings\source\server\Tieto.MyMeetings.Tasks\FreeBusy\FreeBusyTasks.cs:line 196
   at Tieto.MyMeetings.Tasks.FreeBusy.FreeBusyTasks.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<GetResourceFreeBusy>b__2() in C:\_Hg\Tieto.MyMeetings\source\server\Tieto.MyMeetings.Tasks\FreeBusy\FreeBusyTasks.cs:line 103
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<---
```

Comment: Tasks don't generate nulls. Returning nulls or setting variables to null generates null. As always, debug your code, make sure you initialize all variables etc

Comment: At least post the *full* exception, including its call stack. `WaitAll` is almost certainly rethrowing an exception thrown by one of the tasks. As it is, the question should probably be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: question edited (call stack added)

Comment: question edited with the P.S. in the Note part

Comment: The call stack points to a problem in GetMeetingRoomsFreeBusyCached. Have you tried debugging ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Task.WaitAll doesn't throw this exception. It *will* rethrow exceptions raised by one of its tasks. Without the full exception and call stack (as returned by `Exception.ToString()`) it's impossible to be sure, but the standard guidance applies here as well - somewhere, somehow, an unininitialized variable or parameter is used.

For example:

```
List<int> personIds;
List<int> meetingRoomIds;

SplitResourceIds(resourceIds, out personIds, out meetingRoomIds);
```

may well set both `personIds` and `meetingRoomIds` to null. This means that

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetResourceFreeBusyOnline(requesterId,
                                                                 personIds.ToArray(), 
                                                                 start, end));
```

will throw an exception inside the task, that will be re-raised when `Task.WaitAll` is called.

To fix this just follow the advice in the duplicate question. Check parameters for null, debug your code, check the full call stack of the exception. `Task.WaitAll` will throw an [AggregateException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception(v=vs.110).aspx) which contains all underlying exceptions in its [InnerExceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.innerexceptions(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

At the very least you should catch the `AggregateException` to handle and log exceptions raised in tasks separately.

Finally, use `async/await`,  `Task.Run` and `await Task.WhenAll` instead of StartNew and Task.WaitAll. `await` unwraps the `AggregateException` and raises the underlying exception, which makes debugging a lot easier.

**UPDATE**

From the call stack it appears that `Tieto.MyMeetings.Tasks.FreeBusy.FreeBusyTasks.GetMeetingRoomsFreeBusyCached` calls `SharpArch.NHibernate.LinqRepositoryWithTypedId'2.FindAll` and either passes a null parameter or a list of items that contain null. These values are probably used to create a session key, since `SharpArch.NHibernate.Web.Mvc.WebSessionStorage.GetSessionForKey` is called before the exception is thrown.

Finding the exact problem requires debugging the code and stepping into `GetMeetingRoomsFreeBusyCached`

Comment: Thanks, You have shown me the correct path and where to find an issue. We are creating the NHIbernate session as a session which was not ready for multithread. So I had to put all the code selecting from DB outside of Tasks.

Comment: You should seriously consider moving to EF or a microORM like Dapper. NHibernate has fallen behind as asynchronous operations would require a complete rewrite. You can't fake asynchronous database operations with extra threads - ADO.NET async operations don't use threads, they use the operating system's IO completion ports to work without blocking any threads. At least make sure that you have the [latest version](http://nhibernate.info/blog/)